# Why is this MockMvc test failing?

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

This is the Controller I have:

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
@RequestMapping(value = "/spittles")
public class SpittleController {

    SpittleRepository spittleRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSpittles(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(spittleRepository.findSpittles(10, 10));
        return "spittles";
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSpittleRepository(SpittleRepository spittleRepository) {
        this.spittleRepository = spittleRepository;
    }

}
```

and the View I have **(spittles)**:

```
<c:forEach items="${spittleList}" var="spittle">
    ${spittle.message}
</c:forEach>
```

which works fine..

However this test fails:

```
    SpittleController spittleController = new SpittleController();
    spittleController.setSpittleRepository(mockRepository);

    MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(spittleController)
            .setSingleView(new InternalResourceView("/WEB-INF/views/spittles.jsp")).build();

    mockMvc.perform(get("/spittles"))
            .andExpect(view().name("spittles"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("spittleList"));
```

with the message:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'spittleList' does not exist
```

But in the jsp, it looks like the model has the attribute **spittleList** , what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After specify the name, is problem still occur?

```
model.addAttribute("spittleList", spittleRepository.findSpittles(10, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can take help of expect to mock your service, look as below:

expect(spittleRepository.findSpittles(10, 10)).andReturn(EXPECTED OUTPUT)